# Avoid multiple calls to fprintf when writing vector of values and newline

Tags: string, matlab, printf

I am outputting values from vectors to a text file using `fprintf`. Is it possible to add a newline character to the end of each vector being printed without requiring two calls to `fprintf`?

Example that produces the desired output `1 2 3 4`, but with two calls to `fprintf` below.

```
A = [1 2 3 4];
fprintf('%d ', A)
fprintf('\n')
```

If you were to try `fprintf('%d \n', A)` for instance, this would produce the undesired effect of adding a newline character after every number printed:

```
>> fprintf('%d \n', A)
1 
2 
3 
4
```

I am asking out of general curiosity. Effect on performance is of course likely minimal.

Comment: Actually the effect on performance could be significant if you have lots of calls like that. The old behaviour of MATLAB's I/O functions is to flush the file buffers after every write. Not sure if is still the case, but I don't believe that these functions are a priority for MathWorks...

Comment: @CST-Link, et al.: If you're writing to a file, there is a means of disabling auto-flush: [High Performance File I/O](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/04/19/high-performance-file-io/). I'm not sure if this works for an array argument in this case or if auto-flush can be disabled in other cases.

Comment: You should probably use `dlmwrite()` if you need good performance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but...

```
fprintf([repmat('%d ',1,numel(A)) '\n'], A)
```

Or, as noted by @nikkola:

```
fprintf([repmat('%d ',1,numel(A)-1) '%d\n'], A)
```

to remove trailing whitespace before newline.

Comment: @GameOfThrows It's amusingly close to `eval` :-)

Comment: Nice idea! Perhaps `fprintf([repmat('%d ',1,numel(A)-1) '%d\n'], A)` to remove trailing whitespace before newline?

Comment: @mikkola Good idea, yes! Edited

Comment: @LuisMendo I think that edit actually makes it even better than the starting version with two `fprintf` calls, which I believe also has the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Another inelegant solution using `sprintf`:

```
A = [1 2 3 4];
fprintf('%s\n',sprintf('%d ', A))
```